# how to efficiently divide a large image to several parts and rotate them?

Tags: python, image, numpy

Given a big picture the following takes a lot of time:

**1**
cut image to 4 evenly shaped images (divide the image one time in the middle horizontally, and divide the image one time vertically):

[image]

**2**
rotate the 4 parts the following way:
[image]

**3** concat (so it will be ready as an input to a neural network to be run as a batch of 4 image)

what i have tried (image is square and :

```
image_A = image_np[: int(size / 2), :, :]
image_B = cv2.flip(image_np[int(size / 2):, :, :], -1)
image_C = cv2.rotate(image_np[:, :int(size / 2), :], cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
image_D = cv2.rotate(image_np[:, int(size / 2):, :], cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)
```

So i was wondering if there's a faster way, given that image/part is a numpy array.

Comment: It is unclear to me from your image, what you start with and what you end up with. could you clarify?

Comment: Is your code giving you the expected outputs?

Comment: @BlueRineS added a clarification, please let me know if it clear now

Comment: First of all, you can only concat them if the original width is equal to the height, right?

Comment: @BlueRineS all parts are of shape (size/2, size) [original image is of shape (size/2, size/2), so i am able to concat them

Comment: Right. So what is wrong with your current code?

Comment: @BlueRineS it is very time consuming

Comment: You mean computationally? Well I don't see the point in the rotation operations. If you end up with the concatenated image as shown, then I would suggest you ditch the rotation part. Assuming it passes through a convolutional layer, the neuron states will receive the same operations anyway.. So maybe ditch that part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could simply get the views for virtually free runtime with array-slicing, like so -

```
B = image_np[-1:int(size / 2)-1:-1, ::-1, :]
C = image_np[::-1, :int(size / 2),:].swapaxes(0,1)
D = image_np[:, -1:int(size / 2)-1:-1, :].swapaxes(0,1)
```

`image_A = image_np[: int(size / 2), :, :]` already seems like a view, so no change(s) required for that one.